# How to intercept setter method with AOP

Tags: java, scala, annotations, aop

I want to do something with a field BEFORE it gets the value assigned with a setter. I created the annotation and the aspect, but I don't know how to get the setter. This is my code:

```
@Aspect
public class AnnotationAspect{

    @Pointcut("@annotation(annotationVariableName)")
    public void annotationPointCutDefinition(Annotation annotationVariableName){
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void atExecution(){}

    @Around("annotationPointCutDefinition(annotationVariableName) && atExecution()")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Annotation annotationVariableName) throws Throwable {
        Object returnObject = null;
        returnObject = joinPoint.proceed();

        return returnObject;
    }
}
```

The annotation @Annotation is applied to a field in scala, so the method is "field =" (I don't know if this can change something). 
Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is the annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Annotation{
}
```

And an example code:

```
class Test{

  @Annotation
  var testing: String =_

}
```

Comment: "the method is "field ="" – no, a setter method in Scala is `field_=`. Whitespace is not legal in Scala method names.

Comment: Please do not just provide aspect code but also the annotation and target class source code. Without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) everyone can just speculate about your problem.

Comment: yes @JörgWMittag you are right, what I wanted to say is that the setter y called like that, if you want to define it you have to do it as you said. I've just edited with the annotation and how I want to use it, I don't have much more like that.